# How blockchain used in benchmarking of pallet?

Tags: pallet, benchmarking

I am implementing benchmarking and just wonder how its working.

For testing we mocking runtime.

Does it mean that data not really written into blockchain, but rather in some mock structure...?

What about benchmarking? Is it mock? release? real blockchain?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific and ask a more singular question. Open ended ones are not very valuable overall typically, https://substrate.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask has some good pointers 

Answer (score 3):

For developing a benchmark in Substrate; you mock the runtime, that is correct.

When you then want to deploy your pallet to a real blockchain, you need to re-execute the benchmarks with the real runtime.
This does not require a change to your benchmarks, but how they are called.
In Polkadot this happens [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/6532750609c66e686d91d6d44cf8c4d0224ff4b7/runtime/polkadot/src/lib.rs#L1713).
This then ensures that all the other runtime configuration is taken into account that could influence your benchmark.

If I misunderstood your question then please extend it a bit to be more concrete.

Comment: Best place to start is the [benchmarking docs](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/benchmarking/) to learn more about what is going on. The last section has further readings an videos to review this as well that are very valuable!